# The difference between C++ array header and normal arrays

Tags: arrays

I am studying c++11 and I found that there is array and vector headers. What is the difference between these type of arrays and the normal arrays without including these headers?

Answer (score 0):

std::array is a container class that encapsulate fixed-size arrays, but std::vector is lot more than that. std::vector can dynamically grow or shrink as you need. This is the main difference between std::array and std::vector

Please see the following C++ reference pages for more information.

[std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

[std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)